# Will a list comprehension make the following code more readable?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm writing a program to parse Linux audits and need to create a map between system call names and numbers. The system calls come from /usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h and take the following format:

```
#define __NR_read 0
#define __NR_write 1
#define __NR_open 2
#define __NR_close 3
```

The following code works:

```
SYSCALLS = {}
SYSCALL_HEADERS="/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h"

with open(SYSCALL_HEADERS) as syscalls:
    for line in syscalls:
        if  "_NR_" in line:
            sysc, syscn = re.split('_NR_| ', line.strip())[2:]
            SYSCALLS[syscn] = sysc
```

But it seems a bit long winded. Is there a way to use a list comprehension to shorten the code and make it a bit more readable?

Comment: I guess this is more a matter of opinion... IMHO long and complex list comprehensions make the code less readable, and should be used carefully if your code is going to be read by other people. I personally like having the help of variables to tell me a bit about the code and its intentions...

Comment: That's a super valid point. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict comprehension to produce the same output:

```
with open(SYSCALL_HEADERS) as syscalls:
    SYSCALLS = {
        syscn: sysc 
        for line in syscalls if  "_NR_" in line
        for sysc, syscn in (re.split('_NR_| ', line.strip())[2:],)}
```

but I don't think that that is any more readable.

Comment: You get a +1, not for correctness (it is correct), but for the comment about not being any more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter, but not necessarily more readable:

```
>>> dict(l.split("_")[3:][0].split(" ")[::-1] for l in f if "_NR_" in l)
{'1': 'write', '3': 'close', '0': 'read', '2': 'open'}
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fixed, but that's making it even worse.

Comment: Yeah, I had considered `dict(genexp)` too but discarded it for that very reason.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
f = open("/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h")    
SYSCALLS = {k:v for line in f.readlines()
            for k,v in (re.split('_NR_| ', line.strip())[2:],)
            if  "_NR_" in line}
```

Comment: There is no need to read the whole file into a list when you can just iterate directly over the file.

Comment: Also, you filter in the wrong place; the `'_NR_' in line` is important because it keeps the `re.split()` from being applied to empty lines.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks again !

Comment: And one more issue: the OP is *swapping* the name and number; the number is the key and the value is the name. Your code produces the dict the wrong way around.